# How do I delete all NA value from my ACCESS Table?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Does a Query like the following one exist :

```
UPDATE FieldName FROM TableName WHERE FieldName IN('NA') SET FieldName = NULL
```

Fact is that `FieldName` can be any field ?

For Example

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | .... | Field100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 013475 | 486466 | 486655 | 156861 | .... | 15351312 |
| 013475 | NA | 486655 | 156861 | .... | 15351312 |
| 013475 | 486466 | NA | 156861 | .... | NA |
| 013475 | 486466 | 486655 | NA | .... | NA |

After Executing query I should have :

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 | Field4 | .... | Field100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 013475 | 486466 | 486655 | 156861 | .... | 15351312 |
| 013475 |  | 486655 | 156861 | .... | 15351312 |
| 013475 | 486466 |  | 156861 | .... |  |
| 013475 | 486466 | 486655 |  | .... |  |

Please kindly note that I'm working on access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you could do is to use some VBA to loop the fields and run a set of update statements. Something like:

```
Sub sUpdateData()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim fld As DAO.Field
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = db.TableDefs("TableName")
    For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        strSQL = "UPDATE TableName SET [" & fld.Name & "]=NULL WHERE [" & fld.Name & "]='NA';"
        db.Execute strSQL
    Next fld
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I think your way Is the fastest one

Comment: It is absolutely the slowest method, as you will run an unnecessary update query for each hit.

Comment: @Gustav but looping a recordset and each field to check each piece of data individually will probably be slower? Only proper benchmarking will tell, and it also may depend on the number of pieces of data that need updating.

Comment: @Applecore: This method will call 100 update queries. It can never be fast. But you are of course right - who knows? You need statistics for the data to guess.

Comment: @Gustav got like 4Mios Cells to check

Comment: That's only 40000 records. Why not make two backups, run the two methods (one method on each backup), and post your results?

Answer (score 0):

Have to explicitly reference each field to update.

Consider example with 2 fields:

```
UPDATE tablename SET Field2 = IIf(Field2 = "NA", Null, Field2),
                     Field3 = IIf(Field3 = "NA", Null, Field3)
```

Alternatively, build VBA procedure to perform edits on recordset or run repetitive UPDATE action statements in a loop.

Otherwise, open table and run a one-time Find/Replace on the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

No. Field and table names in SQL cannot be dynamic.

Use *DAO* for such tasks:

```vb
Public Function CleanNa()

    Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
    Dim Field   As DAO.Field
    
    Dim Sql     As String
    
    Sql = "Select * From Tablename"
    
    Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(Sql)
    
    Records.MoveFirst
    While Not Records.EOF
        For Each Field In Records.Fields
            If Field.Value = "NA" Then
                Records.Edit
                Field.Value = Null
                Records.Update
            End If
        Next
        Records.MoveNext
    Wend
    Records.Close
    
End Function
```

Comment: Well, you have code ready to run. It will probably run much faster than start writing a series of SQL updates that does the same.